# Workaround for superclass mismatch for class SQLiteAdapter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jruby, torquebox

I'm using torquebox 2.0 beta (i.e. jruby on rails). Everything was working fine until I installed the Citier gem.  Once I installed the gem, I began to get the following error:

```
superclass mismatch for class SQLiteAdapter
```

the full error is included in this gist: [Full Trace of Error Message](https://gist.github.com/1547640)

Does anyone have any suggestions for a workaround or a fix for this error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'citier' is assuming a certain class hierarchy for `SQLiteAdapter` and `PostgreSQLadapter`, and that is clashing with JDBC adapters'. I don't know how to fix it; it might be as simple as removing the inheritance specification from the offending line 17, but maybe not. Either way, you should contact citier's author.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have created an issue with the author of the Citier gem.  Thanks again.